# atomic get/load and set/store with older gcc __sync builtins

Tags: c, gcc

I'm working with (a vendor branch of ) gcc 4.6, and need 4 basic atomic operations on an unsigned integer

- Atomic increment
- Atomic decrement
- Atomic set
- Atomic get

. The newer __atomix_XXX builtins are not supported by this gcc version, only the __sync builtins.

This means I can do these operations:

```
#define ATOMIC_INC(ptr) __sync_fetch_and_add((ptr),1)
#define ATOMIC_DEC(ptr) __sync_fetch_and_sub((ptr),1)
#define ATOMIC_GET(ptr) __sync_fetch_and_add((ptr),0)
```

However, I can't find a way to implement an `#define ATOMIC_SET()`, which would atomically set a variable, is there any way to achiece this with gcc 4.6.x ?

Also, is there a better way to implement the above `ATOMIC_GET()` ? The generated assembly does look fine from an atomic point of view, albeit it's sub-optimal due to actually performing an add operation.

EDIT: The architectures in question is ARMv6, x86 and x86_64.

Comment: You're probably in for writing some assembly language.  Your options are radically different depending on which CPU architecture this is.  Please specify.

Comment: You could also use a relatively lightweight library like ConcurrencyKit: http://concurrencykit.org/doc/ck_pr_store.html

Comment: Do you have `__sync_lock_test_and_set`?

Answer (score 7):

The `__sync_xxx()` are modelled on some Intel primitives, and on your x86, atomic load/store are pretty trivial, which I think is why the set appears incomplete.

For atomic store I think you are stuck with `__sync_val_compare_and_swap()`, though like `__sync_fetch_and_add()` for load, it is clearly overkill :-(

There is the "full memory barrier" `__sync_synchronize()`, but I haven't been able to discover what this does (except by experiment, on x86_64) !  If you know exactly what machines you are compiling for, you could have fun sucking and seeing... starting with load and store wrapped in `__sync_synchronize()`.

I can tell you that for x86 and x86_64, atomic loads do not require any extra -- ordinary reads will do.  Atomic stores require an `mfence` if you want `memory_order_seq_cst`, but not otherwise.  HOWEVER... the other thing missing from the `__sync_xxx` family is a *compiler* barrier... unless that's what `__sync_synchronize()` actually does !!

---

Added later...

I recommend [C/C++11 mappings to processors](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html) for a good description of how atomics can/should be implemented on x86/x86_64, ARM and PowerPC.

To use `__sync_val_compare_and_swap()` as an atomic store of an `int`:

```
  void a_store(int* p_ai, int val)
  {
    int ai_was ;

    ai_was = *p_ai ;
    do { ai_was = __sync_val_compare_and_swap (p_ai, ai_was, val) ;
  } ;
```

On your x86/x86_64, for memory_order_seq_cst (SC), you need either a `LOCK XCHG` or a `MOV` followed by an `MFENCE`... so using `LOCK CMPXCHG` in a loop is a little painful.  For the ARM, this is also a little painful, but more so :-(

---

Hand-rolling the atomic load/store is strictly for the brave (or the foolhardy)... and, depending on what __sync_synchronize() actually does on a given machine, *may or may not work* !

So, the trivial approach is:

```
   __sync_synchronize() ;
   v = v_atomic ;           // atomic load !
   __sync_synchronize() ;

   __sync_synchronize() ;
   v_atomic = v ;           // atomic store !
   __sync_synchronize() ;
```

Which, for x86/x86_64 compiles (for me, on gcc 4.8 for x86_64) to:

```
    mfence
    mov    xxx, xxx
    mfence
```

for load and store.  Which is definitely safe (and SC)... for load it may or may not be better than `LOCK XADD`... for store it may be better than `LOCK CMPXCHG` and the loop around it !

If (*and only if*) for ARM this compiles to:

```
    dmb
    ldr/str
    dmb
```

Then that to is safe (and SC).

Now... for x86/x86_64 for the *processor* you don't need any `MFENCE` *at all* for load, not even for SC.  But you do need to stop the *compiler* from reordering stuff.  The `__sync_synchronize()` does that as well as planting the `mfence`.  For gcc you can construct a `__sync_compiler()` with the following voodoo:

```
  #define __sync_compiler() __asm__ __volatile__("":::"memory")
```

I fondly believe that `__sync_synchronize()` (for x86/x86_64) is effectively:

```
  #define __sync_mfence() __asm__ __volatile__("mfence":::"memory")
```

Because the x86/x86_64 is so well behaved you could:

```
    __sync_compiler() ;
    v = v_atomic ;            // atomic load -- memory_order_seq_cst
    __sync_compiler() ;

    __sync_compiler() ;
    v_atomic = v ;            // atomic store -- memory_order_seq_cst
    __sync_synchronize() ;
```

AND... if you can live with memory_order_release, then you can replace the only remaining `_sync_synchronize()` by a `_sync_compiler()` !

Now, for the ARMv7... if (*and only if* -- I do not have an ARM, so cannot test this) `__sync_synchronize()` compiles to `dmb`, then we can do ever so slightly better for load:

```
    __sync_compiler() ;
    v = v_atomic ;            // atomic load
    __sync_synchronize() ;
```

for all memory orders: memory_order_seq_cst and _acquire (and _consume).

And for memory_order_release we can:

```
    __sync_synchronize() ;
    v_atomic = v ;            // atomic store -- memory_order_release
    __sync_compiler() ;
```

For the ARMv8 it seems that there are special `LDA` and `STL` instructions... but I am somewhat out of my depth here.

NB: this is following [C/C++11 mappings to processors](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html) which I have faith in, but cannot testify to the truth of for the ARM.

Anyway... if you are prepared to hand-roll the atomic load/store, then you can do better.

So... if the speed of these things *really matters*, I would be tempted to hand-roll, assuming a restricted number of target architectures, and noting that:

- you are using gcc specific stuff anyway, so the `__sync_compiler()` trick does not introduce an *extra* portability issue.
- the `__sync_xxx` family has been superceded by the more complete `__atomic_xxx` in gcc, so if you were to need to add another target architecture in future, then you might then be able to upgrade to `__atomic_xxx`.
- and, in the not too distand future, standard C11 atomics will be generally available, so solving portability issues could be punted.

Comment: __sync_synchronize() is a memory barrier(e.g. produces an mfense instruction), and the __sync_xxx documentation seems to imply they're also a memory barrier. How would I use __sync_val_compare_and_swap to implement a store ?

Comment: your `a_store` function is invalid; the `do` statement is incomplete